# PySerial Reporting 'Resource Busy' for seemingly unused serial port

Tags: python, macos, serial-port, usb, pyserial

I am attempting to open a serial connection to a usb device using PySerial, and with the following code I am getting the following error:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-EN270425')
```

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
OSError: [Errno 16] Resource busy: '/dev/tty.usbserial-EN270425'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-EN270425')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 16] could not open port /dev/tty.usbserial-EN270425: [Errno 16] Resource busy: '/dev/tty.usbserial-EN270425'
```

I have checked to see if there was a process using the resource via
`lsof | grep "/dev/tty.usbserial-EN270425"` and got no return value.

I was able to connect to the port on a different machine, the only difference being operating system and python version. The machine that CAN connect is running Mac OS Mojave and Python 3.6, the machine that CANNOT connect is running Mac OS Catalina and Python 3.8. Does anyone have any idea on where I can move forward from here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is not with python or your code, but with the drivers for your USB serial device, so make sure you have proper drivers installed.

In my case it was an FTDI serial cable. I fixed the issue by installing official FTDI drivers from [here](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm). Make sure to allow access in System Preferences when asked. I also had to reboot and disconnect/reconnect USB a couple of times before it took.

The same code as OP should work once the drivers are working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I also used the FTDI cable and USB dongles.
In my case, I attached the dongle to Mac(OS is Catalina) and used it for Windows OS by using Parallel Desktop.

But, after disconnecting it from Windows and connect to Mac to send a signal with Pyserial, the script left the same error message.

While the dongle is connected to Windows, it works well in Windows software.

So, probably, this problem is not from the driver issues.

---

I can make the same situation with AirPods.
Here is what I have done below.

```
ls -l /dev/tty.*
```

crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   0 Mar  6 19:11 /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port

crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   2 Mar  6 19:11 /dev/tty.adkslmAirPods-Wirelessi

```
% lsof  /dev/tty.adkslmAirPods-Wirelessi
```

COMMAND    PID         USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

python3.7 4920 ---  89u   CHR   18,2      0t0  641 /dev/tty.adkslmAirPods-Wirelessi

% kill 4920

From here, Python script

`import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/tty.adkslmAirPods-Wirelessi')`

Here is the error message I can make.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/---/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
>       self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
>   OSError: [Errno 16] Resource busy: '/dev/tty.adkslmAirPods-Wirelessi'. 
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/---/Documents/GitHub/Script/Python/behavioral_analysis/test.py", line 4, in 
>       ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/tty.adkslmAirPods-Wirelessi')
>   File "/Users/---/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in **init**
>       self.open()
>     File "/Users/---/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
>       raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
>   serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 16] could not open port /dev/tty.adkslmAirPods-Wirelessi: [Errno 16] Resource busy: '/dev/tty.adkslmAirPods-Wirelessi'
>   `